KVL when given "wrong direction" current

For some reason my calculation isn't correct. The mutual inductance is minus sign at both sides according to the points.
Look at left circuit now. I follow the given current and write + on the upper part of the inductor. When I reach v1 I meet - sign as given. So KVL is: $$Left: V_{L1}-V_1-V_m=0$$
Which is correct according to the answers. But when I apply the same logic for the right circuit it's wrong. Following i2 I write + on the lower part of the inductor. When I get to v2 I meet + sign so it will be + in kvl: $$Right: V_{L2}+V_2-V_m=0$$
Which is wrong. For some reason V2 should be negative here

Are you trying to follow the direction arrows shown in your diagram? Or are you trying to make $i_2$ go counter-clockwise so that you will have both currents entering the transformer at the polarity dot?

The current loop direction looks correct to me (both clockwise), so V2 being positive is correct.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/228708/thevenin-generator-of-circuit-with-coupled-coils   and https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/119656  if you search there may be more

Nodes with dots have voltages that are in phase with respect to their respective undotted terminal. Basic transformers 101.

Current \$i_1(t)\$ enters the \$L_1\$ dot and \$i_2(t)\$  exits the coupled \$L_2\$ dot.  This is in agreement with the currents \$i_1\$ and \$i_2\$ in your diagram.  Because current is entering the non-dotted side of \$L_2\$, the voltage drop due to self inductance will be negative with respect to \$v_2(t)\$ however, the mutual inductance will be positive with respect to \$v_2(t)\$.
Another example to showcase of self and mutual inductance with dot convention: Mutual inductance dot convention
Edit: Added more ways to think about this...
Let's consider what will give us the final value of \$v_1(t):\$

The left black body's output current \$i_1(t)\$
The self inductance of \$L_1\$ produces a voltage drop of \$L_1\frac{di_1(t)}{dt}\$

Note: The self inductance is positive because current is assumed to enter the + terminal of an inductor.  This is separate from the dots used for mutual inductance.  We can separate these voltage contributions and add them later during KVL due to linearity.


The mutual inductance of \$L_2\$ to \$L_1\$ produces a reverse polarity voltage of \$-M_{21}\frac{di_2(t)}{dt}\$

Note: The "reversed" polarity is with respect to the self-inductance + terminal (not-shown but assumed to be the terminal that current \$i_1(t)\$ enters).  This can be derived from the dot mismatch between the LH-loop and RH-loop's noted currents.  Current \$i_2(t)\$ non-dotted end of \$L_2\$, therefore the + terminal of the mutual inductance voltage will be at the non-dotted end of \$L_1\$.



Similarly, consider what will give us the final value of \$v_2(t):\$

The right black body's output current
The self inductance of \$L_2\$ produces a voltage drop of \$L_2\frac{di_2(t)}{dt}\$
The mutual inductance of \$L_1\$ to \$L_2\$ produces a reverse polarity voltage of \$-M_{12}\frac{di_1(t)}{dt}\$

Therefore the KVL equations for each loop assuming \$M_{21}=M_{12}=M\$:
$$
v_1(t)-L_1\frac{di_1(t)}{dt}-\Big[-M\frac{di_2(t)}{dt}\Big]=0\\
v_2(t)-L_2\frac{di_2(t)}{dt}-\Big[-M\frac{di_1(t)}{dt}\Big]=0
$$
TLDR... use the current flow interpretation of the dot convention to solve for mutually induced voltage: **If current enters the dotted terminal of one coil, the induced voltage on the other coil will be positive at its dotted terminal. **

We didn't learn it that way. We learned that first you write KVL as there was no mutual inductance. Then you add M*I term for it. I is the current on the inductor that is inducting the one we are calculating at. So if calculating loop of L1 it is MI2. The sign of the mutual inductance is positive if both currents go in/out of the dot side, negative else
